# d3 this.getBBox().x not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to reverse some text in my code. Meaning that I want to put the text inside my bar if its position + its width is longer than 720 (my domain) - some padding. It works to start, but then "this.getBBox().x" goes haywire.

```
    enterTransition.select(".barLabels")
        .each(function() {
        if ( this.getBBox().x + this.getBBox().width >  720 - elemPadding ) {
            console.log(this.getBBox());
            console.log('Will reverse');
            d3.select(this).attr("dx", -this.getBBox().width-elemPadding*2)
            .attr("fill", "white");
        }
        });
```

(BTW I'm doing this in a hierarchical chart).

Pic of this.getBBox() before going up or down in the hierarchy [here](http://prntscr.com/7kt7xw)

Pic of the same this.getBBox() after coming back to the same tier [here](http://prntscr.com/7kt7kk)

Comment: Define "haywire". Better still, post a minimum working example.

Comment: @CoolBlue by 'haywire' I mean coming out as a huge number I can't work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what it was. this.getBBox().x was giving me the wrong result so I used x(d.value) instead.

```
    enterTransition.select(".barLabels")
        .each(function(d){
            var xPos = x(d.value);
            if ( xPos + this.getBBox().width > height - elemPadding ) {
                d3.select(this).attr("dx", - this.getBBox().width - elemPadding*2)
                .attr("fill", "white");
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want the label position to go to the left instead of the right on the plot. To do this you need to change the following to do width - this.getBBox().width-elemPadding*2. I am assuming that 720 is your width of the plot area...

```
enterTransition.select(".barLabels")
    .each(function() {
    if ( this.getBBox().x + this.getBBox().width >  720 - elemPadding ) {
        console.log(this.getBBox());
        console.log('Will reverse');
        d3.select(this).attr("dx", 720 -this.getBBox().width-elemPadding*2)
        .attr("fill", "white");
    }
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hm. This Doesn't seem to do the trick. Let me see if I can explain this a little more. Here is the graph on first load: http://prntscr.com/7kth7y This is how it should properly be displayed. This is what happens when I go down and back up: http://prntscr.com/7kv6vn And finally, this is the console log for the pre and post http://prntscr.com/7kv7a7 Maybe you can help me.

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin can you log this.getBBox().width and this.getBBox().x and see what they return when you transition?

Comment: I just figured it out actually. About to answer it.